# Variations of [aɪ] in English

Tags: phonetics, american-english

I'm learning IPA and am surprised that some standard American English sounds which seem subtly different to me are all recorded as [aɪ].

Consider the phrase "I like the night", which I understand would be rendered as [aɪ laɪk ðə naɪt].

But to my ear the vowel sound in "I" is pretty different from the sound in "night", which is closer to the sound in a word like "yikes".

Am I hearing a difference that isn't there? Am I hearing a difference that is there, but is represented by diacritic markings I haven't yet learned? Or something else?

Comment: What do you think of the vowels in "right" and "ride"?

Comment: In very clear speech, the three ‘ayes’ in that sentence will be (roughly) identical, except that the one in _night_ is subject to pre-fortis clipping, so it’s a little shorter than the others. In natural speech, however, the word _I_ will usually be reduced to just [a̠], a monophthong realised somewhere in between a front /a/ (as in _cat_) and a back /ɑ/ (as in _father_).

Comment: And the nucleus of the /ay/ diphthongs in _night_ and _like_ will be [ə] instead of [a]. That's normal American; Canadian raising does the same thing for the /aw/ diphthong. it's a case of analogy producing regularity. Most USAns can't hear that the /ay/'s in _hide_ and _height_ don't sound the same, but they can hear that the /aw/'s in Canadians' _loud_ and _lout_ are different.

Comment: @user6726 "right" and "ride" sound quite different to me. "right" sounds like "night" or "light"; "ride", like "hide", "wide", or perhaps the middle of "why".

Comment: This "Canadian Raising" thing also exists in some dialects in the US. One test of the status of that is whether "rider" and "writer" are pronounced the same. I have a little difference in "write" and "ride", but no difference in "writer" and "rider"; I know some folks from the East coast who sound normal to me, but they actually distinguish "writer" and "rider". I have competing hypotheses about your situation. One is that you have a Canadian Raising-type dialect with phonological raising. The second is that you are more acutely sensitive to the subtle difference as in my dialect.

Comment: IMO it is not a good idea to refer to matters of pronunciation by reference to "as in the English word X", instead, we need multi-token recordings, so that we can hear how you actually say it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks. I will look up pre-fortis clipping. But I thought "cat" was transcribed [kæt]?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The [ai] of "like" precedes a voiceless stop, so isn't that one subject to pre-fortis clipping, too?

Comment: @RosieF It is, yes. Not sure how I managed to miss that.

Comment: @algal The a in _cat_ is variously transcribed /a/ or /æ/, depending on convention. /a/ is more common when describing British English, where it’s less ‘flat’ than in American English.